# Связи sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

есть 4 таблицы связанные один ко многим. Подскажите как получить сразу все данные из дочерних таблиц не используя getTables() для каждой из них. Спасибо.

```
User.hasMany(Table1);
User.hasMany(Table2);
User.hasMany(Table3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто указать соответствующие модели в запросе в опции `include`:

```
 const user = await  db.User.findByid(userId, {
   include: [{
     model: db.Table1,
     separate: true // обязательно указать!
   }, {
     model: db.Table2,
     separate: true // обязательно указать!
   }, {
     model: db.Table3,
     separate: true // обязательно указать!
   }]
 })
```

`separate: true` необходимо для того, чтобы всё не было один запросом и записи все таблиц не умножались.

Comment: Можете уточнить значение параметра separate? Что значит "записи все таблиц не умножались"?

Comment: Ну если вы SQL Зарпос напишите и соедините все 4 таблицы то кол-во записей будет равно колв-у записей в таблице 1 умноженному на кол-во записей в таблице 2 и т.д. Чтобы этого избежать, указываем separate: true, тогда основной запрос по User идет отдельно, а для каждой его записи будут выполняться отдельнеы запросы для таблиц table1, Table2, Table3